# busqueda especifica en excel

Tags: excel

Me pueden ayudar a buscar una forma en excel de buscar un valor especifico o encontrar su dato y su fecha como en el ejemplo siguiente:
Si utilizo `buscarV` solo me encontrara el primer registro, lo que necesito saber es una búsqueda que me arroje el valor con su fecha de registro y no la primer fecha que encuentre la formula

```
N10234  27-jun
N10255  29-may
N10273  26-jun
N10273  25-jun
N10273  12-jun
N10276  18-jun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer eso, una solución es:

- Concatenar los dos datos `N1027325JUN`, y hacer lo mismo en la tabla de búsqueda ahí podrá encontrarse el valor con `buscarv`
- Caso contrario debemos recurrir a **vba**, sin embargo es demasiado trabajo para hacerlo programando.

Comment: Gracias Vicente, me has salvado el dia, solo tuve que formatear la fecha (250619) para que no me marcara error y ya pude encontrar con la formula el dato,